# WebLogic 12.1.2 bad record MAC on HTTPS

Tags: https, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm trying to use WebLogic with HTTPS default keystore for development and I get the following error when I try to connect to the server via web browser:

```
ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer', fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
<13-nov-2014 11H48' COT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <[Thread[ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer',5,Thread Group fo
r Queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer']]weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter: SSLENGINE: Exception occurred during SSLEngine.unwrap(ByteBuffer,ByteBu
ffer[]).
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: bad record MAC
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1605)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1573)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:971)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:876)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:750)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:664)
at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$5.run(JaSSLEngine.java:134)
at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:132)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrap(JSSEFilterImpl.java:603)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:507)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.unwrapAndHandleResults(JSSEFilterImpl.java:474)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.isMessageComplete(JSSEFilterImpl.java:313)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:991)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:928)
at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.process(NIOSocketMuxer.java:507)
at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer.processSockets(NIOSocketMuxer.java:473)
at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:30)
at weblogic.socket.SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:43)
at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:147)
at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:119)
>
```

I found some links about this, but nothing important.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Everything sounds like you're not setting `((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "SSLv3" });
((SSLSocket) socket).setUseClientMode(true);` on the client

Comment: Set that value on web browser? I'm not sure about it. My problem occurs when the server process is up and I try to connect via web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the WebLogic Domain data folder and setup it again. This time I restart the WebLogic server domain after the WebLogic Domain data folder setup and enable the SSL after. Next open the browser with the https address and it work.